# time to wait for get keystroke

Tags: x86, keyboard, hardware

i write a program that record keystrokes but some keystrokes are missing when my program delays for some time. how much time i need to delay to read output buffer of intel 8042? this is my source:

```
LABEL0:
IN AL,64H
AND AL,21H
CMP AL,1
JNZ LABEL0
MOV EAX,5000H    ;HERE HOW MUCH TIME I NEED TO READ OUTPUT BUFFER???
LABEL1:
CMP EAX,0
JZ LABEL2
DEC EAX
JMP LABEL1
LABEL2:
IN AL,60H        ;HERE WHEN I CAN READ OUTPUT BUFFER???
```

After how much time can i read the output buffer?

Comment: Read about it [here at OSDev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller#PS.2F2_Controller_IO_Ports).

Comment: i already know all about PS2 I/O ports however you can see at my source above that before my code read port 60h(output buffer) wait a moment. i only want to know how much to wait in windows OS before read the PS2 port  60h?

Comment: If you're really using Windows then you can't read ports with `IN`/`OUT` anyway except for writing a Windows kernel keyboard driver.

Comment: i write a driver in kernel mode for windows if you want to know and i can read IO keyboard controller ports with `IN AL,60H` opcode

Comment: Only want know the time for delay before read the 60H port onto windows OS